# Increase the efficiency of charging

Tags: charging

Is there a way of increasing the efficiency of charging an android device without switching the device off?

I am not talking about using different cables, chargers, hardware etc, I'm interested in methods of decreasing the amount of time it takes to charge using only software or applications.

For example, undervolting your device will mean it uses less power at specified CPU frequencies, so the device will use less power while charging, right?

Comment: Check this link : https://www.androidpit.com/charge-android-phone-faster